# Error parsing XML: Not Well Formed in the Strings file

Tags: android, eclipse, string

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello World, AvanosActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Avanos</string>
<string name="textView1">Who would you like to call?</string>
<string name="password">Enter Password</string>
<string name="callButton2">Call</string>
<string name="phoneNumber">Phone Number</string>
<string name="EnterButton">Enter</string>
<string name="ChangePasswordButton">Change Password</string>
<string name="CurrentPassword">Enter Current Password:</string>
<string name="NewPassword">Enter New Password:</string>
<string name="settings">Settings</string>
<string name="EnterButton2">Enter</string>
<color name="Black">#000000</color>
<item format="string" name="root" type="id">1</item>
```

In my app, I added a new button entitled "ChangePasswordButton". According to Eclipse, I made a mistake when I added this string element. This has never happened before. Everything seems to be in order, but it's not working for some reason. Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First char should be '<'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```